# Too Many Records in salesforce

Tags: soql, query, group-by

I have More amount of Records in salesforce, i have created field as not Unique.So for account Records is created with duplicate Records also,I want to check how many Records contain dulplicate Records

for that I have wrote Query :
I have lot of account records, i don't want to use limit for filtering the records when querying, i want to query all the records in salesforce.

But when i use:

```
SELECT JDE_ship_to_account_no__c, count(Id) records FROM account
GROUP BY JDE_ship_to_account_no__c HAVING count(Id) > 1
```

for that they suggested answer for this question:

https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/144057/empty-rows-without-limit-in-soql/144068?noredirect=1#comment209183_144068

How to write a batch apex code for above scenario, account records contain duplicates or Not?

I want to check all the records whether the record contain duplicates or Not

Comment: Why dont you just export the records and do a count in a spreadsheet ( Excel or Google docs) ? You would already have the required duplicates by now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't group by a field and have an unlimited group by without a limit. You'll get an error saying that AggregateResult doesn't support queryMore.

This means that your only real option is process every record in the database and perform queries on each iteration, in batch. Something like this:

```
global class X implements Database.Batchable<SObject> {
    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext context) {
        return Database.getQueryLocator('select JDE_ship_to_account_no__c from account');
    }
    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext context, Account[] scope) {
        set<string> shipToVals = new set<String>();
        for(Account record: scope) {
            shipToVals.add(record.jde_ship_to_account_no__c);
        }
        AggregateResult[] ar = [SELECT jde_ship_to_account_no__c
            from account where jde_ship_to_account_no__c in :shipToVals
            group by jde_ship_to_account_no__c
            having count(jde_ship_to_account_no__c) > 1];
        // More queries/processing here
    }
}
```

Comment: I will execute the code through Anonymous window

Comment: @user36188 this class must already be saved and deployed. You might need to do your processing offline if you need to figure out the data for all accounts.

Comment: ok sfdcfox thank you, wait i will check, i any query , i will post question here

Comment: then how to check the output, when i execute anonymous window it is showing error like Global type must be contained inside of a global class

Comment: i want to check the output like system.debug(ar); to know my result,How to execute the batch apex code,I am new to Batch apex,Please gude me sfdcfox

Comment: @user36188 A batch class may produce many logs. You'll have to read each of them. Honestly, it'd be far easier to use an external reporting tool, or even Microsoft Excel, which can tell you how many duplicates there are fairly easily. You won't find a way to do this in pure Apex Code.

Comment: @user36188, I have just learned about Asynchronous Apex and some pretty good guidance using [this](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/asynchronous_apex/async_apex_batch) Trailhead. Take some time to look into it, highly recommended.

Comment: @sfdcfox while sving the class in apex class it is showing error like:: X: Class must implement the global interface method: void finish(Database.BatchableContext) from Database.Batchable<SObject> at line 1 column 14

Comment: @sfdcfox how to rectify the error

Comment: @user36188 The code in this answer is only a fragment. You also need to implement the finish method, which is simply `global void finish(database.batchablecontext context) { }` unless you want to do more.