# SOQL Query in salesforce

Tags: soql

I have Large amount of Account Records in salesforce, i want to check the particular field contain duplicates or Not using Query

For Small amount of Records finding duplicates using query:

```
SELECT JDE_ship_to_account_no__c, count(Id) records FROM account
GROUP BY JDE_ship_to_account_no__c HAVING count(Id) > 1
```

**For Large amount of account Records it is Displaying the empty Value , Please guide the answer to write the query for finding the duplicates for large amount of Records
How to write soql query for finding duplicates for large amount of account records**

Comment: When you say "large", what volume are you talking about? SOQL can return up to 50,000 records.

Comment: i am having morethan  50,000 records,  that time how to write the query? @DanJones

Comment: how to find all the records contain duplicates or not, what is the solution?

Comment: Batch Apex is the answer

Comment: @Eric http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/144608/changes-in-apex-code?noredirect=1#comment210110_144608 please suggest answer for this link

Comment: To me, this sounds like your first focus should be on making improvements to your future data quality. If you clean up your data, but still allow people to enter duplicates, you'll just end up in the same situation that you currently find yourself in (except you'll have even more data to go through next time).

Comment: Please stop asking the same question over and over again: [Too Many Records in salesforce](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/144582/too-many-records-in-salesforce)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see at least 3 ways to do this:

1. Batch Apex, as already mentioned. Code required.
2. Export you data using Data Loader, than find doubles using external tools like MS Excel.
3. Create Summary report with [grouping](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=reports_builder_fields_groupings.htm&language=en_US) by your column. No code required. I believe this is the simplest way.

Comment: can you ellaborate the grouping method from the begining step, i clicked the setup in the salesforce then after where i find this grouping @maovrn

Comment: If you are talking about the third method, you have to [create new report](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=reports_builder_create.htm&language=en_US) at Report tab. It can't be created from the Setup menu.

Comment: I am talking about the third method, after creating the new report and then ? @Maovrn

Comment: When you created new report, you need to select appropriate Report Type - please select Account report type. Report builder is opened. You need to change format of the report from Tabular to Summary, then drag-and-drop JDE_ship_to_account_no__c field into the "Drop a field here to create a grouping" zone of the report - so it is marked as a grouping field.  So now you can see each value and how many records have this value in the JDE_ship_to_account_no__c field.

Comment: In additional you can add RowCount formula field to use conditional highlighting. Unfortunately it is not possible to hide values that have no doubles similar to "HAVING count(Id) > 1".

Comment: it is showing only  limited records where the row count option is there in reports@maovrn , i want to display all the account records where is the row count option is there

Comment: The report builder shows few records as an example. You have to run the report to see all of them. Please click "Run report" button.

Comment: I clicked run report and process is executed but where row count option is there?

Comment: Customize your report, please drag "Add formula" field and drop into your report. Write just "RowCount" word in the formula - it is internal field that now can be displayed in the report.